64GB Ram on Dell G5 5590
Does anyone knows if this is 'file explorer' problem or the RAM problem?
I bought two bar of 32GB RAM (64GB kit) from Crusial last week and just installed it Saturday. Bios recognizes the new RAM, task manager and window system also recognizes it. Games and every apps works fine on it, except 'file explorer'. All tasks involve big files (>150mb) like compressing, extracting, moving, or deleting are super slow and my cooling fans roar like crazy. The average speed is about 500KBs. I feel like only 'file explorer' doesn't recognize the ram and it used cpu or gpu for those tasks.
Yes, I read that on official page of Dell that this model support only 32GB Ram max. But I also saw posts of other owners saying theirs 64GB works so I got greedy.




When you reinstall the original modules does the behavior go away? Dell G5 5590 isn't that descriptive. There are far to many possible configurations of that server.

I just found out about the slow today. Probably will try that tomorrow, as I need to turn it off and give it a night to cooldown. (I read somewhere you supposed to do it)

That sounds like an old wives' tale that has no truth connected to it. I work on servers all day, pull them from their racks, then replace the hardware and turn them on immediately when I am done.

There are more bottlenecks on a computer than just memory. File Explorer doesn't use much memory itself, and I'm struggling to think of any secondary process within File Explorer that would need more than a few hundred MB. Perhaps unzipping files, but even that usually uses more storage than RAM. If File Explorer is running slowly, it is probably not due to a lack of RAM, beyond a good baseline amount, which you're already past. So I'm not sure the problem you see was going to be solved by RAM to begin with, and the problems you're still seeing are evidence of that.

update: I just swapped out the original RAM in. That same file still takes like 10 minutes to copy. Basically the same average speed as the 64GB RAM.
Is there some kind of software that test the performance of RAM?

Background
Based on the specs of Dell G5 5590, 32GB is the maximum officially supported memory size. But it's always possible that Dell doesn't want to validate support for 64GB memory for cost saving purposes, or hardware stability reasons.
I would explore a few possible reasons.
Is the number of files too large?
Your screenshot shows that there are 70,000+ files to copy. Given this large amount files, it can be time-consuming to copy even though the total size is small. I would try to copy one big 500M file to another location and see if the speed is normal. If not...
Is it File Explorer or Code Related to File Operations?

All tasks involve big files (>150mb) like compressing, extracting, moving, or deleting are super slow and my cooling fans roar like crazy.

All these tasks use RAM heavily: Files are first read into RAMs, either fully or by chunks, before they are written to the disk.
One possibility is that the File Explorer uses some low-level maneuvers, which are supposed to speed up, hit some incompatibilities as your RAM configuration is unsupported. To eliminate this possibility, I would try to use a third-party file manager such as mu commander for the same tasks, and see if the tasks are done at a normal speed.
If the answer is yes, then I guess File Explorer has triggered some hardware incompatibilities and you would have to use a third-party file manager in place of File Explorer.
If the answer is no, then...
I don't know, maybe this RAM configuration truly isn't that stable and Dell doesn't want to support it.

I try moving and extracting that same folder by WinRAR. It is faster than file explorer, but I am not sure how it works with my old ram. Will try

update: I tried mu-commander to copy that same file. It takes roughly the same time, maybe a bit slower. I also just swapped out the original RAM in. That file still takes like 10 minutes to copy. Basically the same average speed compare to the 64GB RAM.
Is there some kind of software that test the performance of RAM?

Maybe give this a try: https://www.passmark.com/products/performancetest/pt_advmem.php?srsltid=AfmBOoptLE2bN5M93aXRhQB1ZjCCOvXer8m8AmPzPqtDi9Y22ugrigtr did you install a RAM with the same frequency as before?

The original 16GB is 2666 and my 64GB is 3200. Crucial didn't have the 2666 version and somehow it was also more expensive.
